# Angular 4 wrapping components with _ngcontent-cx divs

Tags: angular, angular2-template

I have an *ngFor* loop in one of my Angular templates that includes another component, here's a snippet:

```
<div *ngFor="let thing of things" (click)="onClick($event, thing)">
    <app-thing [data]="thing"></app-thing>
</div>
```

and Angular is wrapping each **app-thing** with a div containing an attribute called **_ngcontent_c4** as follows:

```
<div _ngcontent_c4>
    <app-thing...>
        <!-- ... -->
    </app-thing>
</div>
<div _ngcontent_c4>
    <app-thing...>
        <!-- ... -->
    </app-thing>
</div>
<div _ngcontent_c4>
    <app-thing...>
        <!-- ... -->
    </app-thing>
</div>
<!-- ... --->
```

The parent div wrapper is causing issues, especially with styling, and making it harder to use the *:host* selector to style the component itself. I had to move some styling outside the *:host* to target the parent to get my flexbox layout working properly.

Is there a way to get Angular not to wrap components?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of iterating the components within a div, rather iterate the component itself, this will apply (this) styles.

```
<div *ngFor="let thing of things" (click)="onClick($event, thing)">
    <app-thing [data]="thing"></app-thing>
</div>
```

Rather do this:

```
<app-thing *ngFor="let thing of things" (click)="onClick($event, thing)" [data]="thing"></app-thing>
```

This will make styling easier, and will keep your styles within its component, like you intended it to.

Answer (score 3):

You can control how Angular applies styles to your components by seting `encapsulation` property in component metadata:

```
@Component({
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
})
export class Component {}
```

`ViewEncapsulation.None` will not add extra attributes. Check [ViewEncapsulation](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/ViewEncapsulation-enum.html) and [Component Styles](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/component-styles.html) in docs for more info.